# Event in VB.Net when Access updated

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am programming an application using VB.Net. My project is when I click to cell on Excel file and run macro, it will send data from cell to Access. My app just shows the database.

But my problem is how can I trigger in my VB.Net app (refresh app) when a record in Access is changed (records in Access either updated or inserted), or is there any event which will do something when Access is changed?

Comment: There is no way with an Access database.  You would just have to poll the database intermittently.  You can do it with a SQL Server database using the SqlDependency class and other "proper" databases might have something similar but Access databases are just files.

Comment: You could use a [`FileSystemWatcher()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a notification when the Access file has been modified.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for your hint. I done everything in access database and it will take more time in case I change to SQL server database. FileSystemWatcher()  that sound good. Let me search more about it :))

Comment: @Bruce if you have access to sql server the migration can be done very fast and smooth, you can load the access file with ssms IDE and all the tables will be created on the database of sql server,  also you can still use `System.Data.OleDb` namespace if you prefer over `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Comment: @jonathana That look a great suggestion but I am currently working on access file, and I am no good at sql server. It's take a little time to search and programing again for my app. But Thanks you so much for your great suggestion. I think I will work with sql server after i solve this problem. I currently read your code below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was curious about `FileSystemWatcher()` that was mentioned in a comment by @Jimi. 
so i wrote a basic program that updates DataGridView after every change in access db file. i have tested it and its working.

**clarifications**:
1. the purpose of that code is for demonstrating the basic principals regarding to OP question and needs some improvements and modularity.

 2. SqlDependency is a much better solution if you can use sql server.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        UpdateDgv()
        watch()
    End Sub


    Private Sub UpdateDgv()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
        DataGridView1.DataSource = GetDatatableFromAccess()
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateDgvThread()
        RemoveHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged
        DataGridView1.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf UpdateDgv))
        AddHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged
    End Sub

    Public watcher As FileSystemWatcher

    Private Sub watch()
        watcher = New FileSystemWatcher()
        watcher.Path = "c:\Users\john\Desktop\Desktop 01-04-2017\"
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite
        watcher.Filter = "*.*"
        AddHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    End Sub


    Private Sub OnChanged(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As FileSystemEventArgs)
        Debug.WriteLine("file was changed")
        ' update datagridview
        Dim t1 As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf UpdateDgvThread)
        t1.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetDatatableFromAccess() As DataTable

        Dim connString As String =
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\john\Desktop\Desktop 01-04-2017\Database11.accdb"

        Dim results As New DataTable()

        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connString)
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM TestTable", conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            adapter.Fill(results)
        End Using

        Return results
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: This is very helpful example. I tested and It was worked for me too. however, you and  jmcilhinney were right, I think this is just a temporary solution for my problem. For future, I think I had to change to sql database :))

Comment: glad i could help (-: